# Property vs Method, which is better for interaction with data member?

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I am exploring c# concepts and would like to know which approach is better for enabling user interaction with a field: Creating a property vs Creating public member functions.
**Approach#1**

```
public class Account
{
    private decimal balance; 

    public decimal Balance 
    {
        get => GetBalance();
        set => SetBalance(value);
    }        
    private decimal GetBalance() 
    {
        return balance;
    }        
    private void SetBalance(decimal balanceValue)
    {
        if(balanceValue >= 0)
           this.balance = balanceValue;
    }
}
```

**Approach#2:**

```
public class Account
{
    private decimal balance;

    public decimal GetBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }
    public void SetBalance(decimal balanceValue)
    {
        if (balanceValue >= 0)
            this.balance = balanceValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't do anything specific when that `balance` is set, then you can simply have `public decimal Balance { get; set; }`. Otherwise, it depends on what operations are performed on a set of internal Fields or other Properties, other method calls, objects created. Sometimes you expose a public method that does ~the same thing as an existing public Property, but overload the method to provide more functionalities and set multiple Fields/Properties at once, controlling possible *cascading effects* that may occur setting the corresponding properties. Many design options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use properties as long as they return fast. That's what they are for. In your first approach, you should remove the superfluous private methods as well:

```
public class Account
{
    private decimal balance;
    public decimal Balance
    {
        get => balance;
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
                throw new ArgumentException();
            this.balance = balanceValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Microsoft has listed some property design guidelines in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/property??WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077).

Simple Get* and Set* methods are effectively replaced by properties in C#.

Properties should not do something that may take a while or kick off some asynchronous operation though.

Comment: Thank you, the property design guideline helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I vote for *property*, which is more *readable*, natural in the context (please note, that Java doesn't have properies, so we have to implement `getBalance`, `setBalance` methods there; in C# we have a choice):

```
public class Account
{
    private decimal m_Balance; 

    // You don't have to extract GetBalance / SetBalance methods;
    // let's have all the logics being incapsulated within the property  
    public decimal Balance {
      get => m_Balance;
      set => m_Balance = value >= 0
        ? value
        : throw new ArgumentOutOfRange(nameof(value)); 
    } 
}
```

I doubt if you should *swallow* `Balance < 0` case; throwing exception is often a better policy